# How can I know when to stop golfing?

Tags: discussion, code-golf

For example, I've spent several days reducing [an assembly submission](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/269554/108687) from an initial **456** bytes down to <del>**330**</del> **322** bytes.

How can I determine when a code golf solution has reached its most compressed or optimized form?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this doesn't ask about the site, this is off-topic here. However, you can ask it in the main site.

Comment: unofficially, there was a challenge that came up with a handicap system, that you can use to compare your handicap-adjusted score with others in the challenge. It's not fool-proof but it can give you a ball park idea of when your answer is approximately golfed ~enough~.  https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/71117/the-ppcg-handicap-system

Answer (score 11, accepted):

## You can't know when a program is done, but you can know when you are done

Determining whether a general program can be shortened is equivalent to the halting problem. There is no algorithm that can be run to check.

You should instead stop golfing when further work on a particular program isn't fun for you. If you are out of ideas, it's better to go do something else than to just stare at the screen.

Comment: There are obvious [cases](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/269585/119544) where shortening isn't possible.  But, for any non-trivial code, yeah, it's tricky to determine if an optimal solution has been reached. Thanks!